# in dataframe , how to merge two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in dataframe , how to merge two rows, like `148` merge `142` to be a new line and drop two them.

```
          title  collectionsCount  subscribersCount  entriesCount  viewsCount
148     Android            697977            100213          6803    10610138
142        Java            103821             65303          1493     1590201
161         iOS            163137             65896          3601     3739843
177  JavaScript            222100             88872          2412     3548736
16       Python             45234             45100          1007      930588
162       Swift             28498             30317          1180      928488
20          PHP             15376             25143           375      329720
62           Go              5321             12881           179      145851
41          C++              3495             18404           101       75019
17            C              2213             14870            50       52019
63         Ruby              1543              6711            40       45162
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge'? Add? Concatenate?

Comment: @DYZ sorry for my english. I think it's "add".

Comment: This still does not help. What do you want to do about the `title` values?

Comment: @DYZ named a new `title` like 'java`. thanks

Comment: If this is a one-time exercise, I suggest that you just add them by hand. If not, you'd better provide a more formal description of what you want to accomplish. Otherwise, it is not clear what you ask. Why 'java'? Why not 'Java'?

Comment: I think `Android` and `Java` is the same language. so I want to merge to only one language like `Java`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136920/discussion-between-liuzhijun-and-dyz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `pandas.Series.replace` to replace `Android` to `Java` then use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` to aggregate the data.

This should work:

```
rules = {'Android':'Java'}
df['title'].replace(rules,inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('title').sum().reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        title  collectionsCount  subscribersCount  entriesCount  viewsCount
0           C              2213             14870            50       52019
1         C++              3495             18404           101       75019
2          Go              5321             12881           179      145851
3        Java            801798            165516          8296    12200339
4  JavaScript            222100             88872          2412     3548736
5         PHP             15376             25143           375      329720
6      Python             45234             45100          1007      930588
7        Ruby              1543              6711            40       45162
8       Swift             28498             30317          1180      928488
9         iOS            163137             65896          3601     3739843
```